# submit two forms with one submit button jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms

I have tried multiple ways of doing this, by searching on stackoverflow for the answer.

I have two forms

Form 1 basic setup:

```
<form action="/post" class="frm-form"  method="post" name="post" 
onsubmit="return vB_Editior['text_editor'].prepare_submit(0,0)" id="quick_reply">
   <textarea></textarea>
      <input type="submit" name="post" value="Send">
</form>
```

Form 2 basic setup:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="tagnotif" style="display:none;" 
onsubmit="return vB_Editor['text_editor'].prepare_submit(0,0)" name="post2" 
method="post" action="/privmsg">
   <input id="username" class="post" type="text" tabindex="1" size="25" 
       name="username[]"style="margin:1px 0"><br />
   <input id="acpro_inp10" class="post" type="text" 
     onkeypress="if (event.keyCode==13){return false}" title="" tabindex="2" 
    maxlength="64" size="45" value="You have been tagged" name="subject"><br />
  <textarea id="textingnotification" rows="15" cols="9"
   name="message" tabindex="3"></textarea>
   <input type="hidden" value="" name="lt">
     <input type="hidden" value="inbox" name="folder">
       <input type="hidden" value="post" name="mode">
</form>
```

I just need these two forms to be submitted on SEND press of first form

TRIED USING THIS CODE VARIABLES WITH THE MAIN SCRIPT: Though it won't pass both, and it won't refresh the page...

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#quick_reply').ajaxForm(function() { 
            alert("Thank you for your submitting form 1"); 
    });
    $('#tagnotif').ajaxForm(function() { 
            alert("Thank you for your submitting form 2"); 
    });

}); 

function mySubmitFunction() {
    $("#quick_reply").submit();
    $("#tagnotif").submit();
}
```

Comment: Why can't you make them one form?

Comment: Make them only one form then ?

Comment: Need to be two separate forms since one sends to /privmsg and the other sends to /post

Comment: never really messed with form coding honestly this is all new. I've know how to make forms, never got into depth with them nor the callbacks or echos of a form via php. Actually don't know php. That and the site wont let me, need to use javascript/jQuery (i know the same written differently tho)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can do two regular post requests from a single html page, because making the post involves leaving the page and following the redirect response.

If you're submitting the forms via [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), why not just make a single ajax button and grab the needed parameters to stick in the request? IE:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'JSON',
  data: {param1: $('input#param1').val(), param2: $('input#param2').val()},
  url: 'url to post to',
  success: (your success callback function goes here)
})
```

Comment: One form is commenting on a form. Other form is for sending PM. Basically my hack here is so when a users tags another user it sends the tagged user a PM stating where the Tag was and that they were tagged. That is why I need to send them both. How would I go about this? No php since I don't have access to it on the hosting site.

Comment: Also creating a AJAX button would be difficult, the first form is generated by a php variable {quick_reply} so yeah I don't actually have access to that bit just the second bit. The second code is hidden this is basically a hack for the site hosting site

Comment: Are you able to change the markup on the page at all, or are you completely stuck with what you have?

Comment: I can change some of it, such as the second form. and a little more around that. why what would you have in mind? I don't mind using Ajax to send the PM function first then the first form to submit afterwards and doing its business (which after submit should go to a confirmation page and then refresh back to that page with the comment in place)

Comment: Oh also I would need to only send if there is data in the input field USERNAME.

Comment: Well, look, you cannot submit two forms from a single HTML page. The internet doesn't work that way. It sounds like the thing you're trying to do (notify user of tag via PM) should happen as part of the callback on the tag. If you want one click to trigger two interactions with the server you're going to have to do it via ajax, neither one of them can be a regular post. If you can't do the entire interaction via ajax (which it sounds like you can't), then you need to handle the pm notification part after the confirmation page is done doing its thing, not as part of this page.

Comment: Confirmation page is also done with php :( So I can't create a time lapse basically? Meaning on click of form1 send form2 PM notification via AJAX then when success of form2 complete form1

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19733/discussion-between-user1760670-and-andrew)

Comment: Checked as answer, up voted @Andrew for the help and sticking with me. It was more complicated than i figured it was. Thanks again Andrew

Answer (score 1):

Doing this first you need to remove every submit buttons from these two forms
If form have submit button this won't work.

First Form

```
<form action="/post" id="frm-form" class="frm-form"  method="post" name="post" 
onsubmit="return vB_Editior['text_editor'].prepare_submit(0,0)" id="quick_reply">
   <textarea></textarea>
      <input id="frm-submit" type="button" name="post" value="Send">
</form>
```

Second Form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="tagnotif" style="display:none;" 
onsubmit="return vB_Editor['text_editor'].prepare_submit(0,0)" name="post2" 
method="post" action="/privmsg">
   <input id="username" class="post" type="text" tabindex="1" size="25" 
       name="username[]"style="margin:1px 0"><br />
   <input id="acpro_inp10" class="post" type="text" 
     onkeypress="if (event.keyCode==13){return false}" title="" tabindex="2" 
    maxlength="64" size="45" value="You have been tagged" name="subject"><br />
  <textarea id="textingnotification" rows="15" cols="9"
   name="message" tabindex="3"></textarea>
   <input type="hidden" value="" name="lt">
     <input type="hidden" value="inbox" name="folder">
       <input type="hidden" value="post" name="mode">
</form>
```

JQuery

```
$("#frm-submit").change(function(){
    $("#frm-form").submit();
    $("#tagnotif").submit();
});
```

This will Refresh the page and submit two forms

Comment: Well now that I don't use jQuery this is useless ;) also we have promises where they could make this simpler and resilient to staggered posting.